# Pandas: Convert time interval integers to times

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I want to convert 5 minute intervals - which are integers - into time format.

For example, below, the 0 interval should become 00:00, the 5 interval should become 00:05, etc.

```
date        interval
2012-10-01  0
2012-10-01  5
2012-10-01  10
2012-10-01  15
2012-10-01  20
2012-10-01  25
2012-10-01  30
2012-10-01  35
2012-10-01  40
```

I thought the following would work:

`df['interval'] = pd.to_datetime(df['interval'], format='%H:%M').dt.hour`

But it returns this error:

`time data 0 does not match format '%H:%M' (match)`

Which is logical, but leaves me unclear as to how to format the `to.datetime` format argument. I can't see anything in the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html) which helps.

---

**Update**

Unfortunately I can't get any of these to work with my actual DataFrame. I should add the further info that the `interval` variable runs from 0 to 2355 over and over. The variable has 17,568 rows of the 0 to 2355 values.

@padraig, with both your answers I get this error:

`ValueError: hour must be in 0..23`

Comment: It wasn't clear from your example that your interval was HHMM format.  I have revised my solution so that it should work with your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you asked for the time, you are probably better off with a Pandas timestamp which records both date and time.

Given your interval you, you can convert that into hours and minutes:

```
df['hour'] = df.interval // 100 
df['mins'] = df.interval.apply(lambda interval: interval % 100)
```

You can now create a timestamp, optionally with a timezone (e.g. UTC):

```
from pytz import UTC

df['timestamp'] = df.apply(lambda row: pd.Timestamp('{0} {1}:{2}'.format(row.date, row.hour, row.mins), tz=UTC), axis=1)

>>> df
         date  interval  hour  mins           timestamp
0  2012-10-01         0     0     0 2012-10-01 00:00:00
1  2012-10-01         5     0     5 2012-10-01 00:05:00
2  2012-10-01        10     0    10 2012-10-01 00:10:00
3  2012-10-01        15     0    15 2012-10-01 00:15:00
4  2012-10-01        20     0    20 2012-10-01 00:20:00
5  2012-10-01        25     0    25 2012-10-01 00:25:00
6  2012-10-01        30     0    30 2012-10-01 00:30:00
7  2012-10-01        35     0    35 2012-10-01 00:35:00
8  2012-10-01        40     0    40 2012-10-01 00:40:00
```

Given the timestamp, you can access the other [properties](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-date-components) such as time as follows:

```
>>> df.timestamp[5].time()
datetime.time(0, 25)
```

If you truly want time as a separate column (formatted as text, but optionally any other desired time format):

```
df['time'] = df.timestamp.apply(lambda time: time.strftime('%H:%M'))

>>> df
         date  interval  hour  mins                  timestamp   time
0  2012-10-01         0     0     0  2012-10-01 00:00:00+00:00  00:00
1  2012-10-01         5     0     5  2012-10-01 00:05:00+00:00  00:05
2  2012-10-01        10     0    10  2012-10-01 00:10:00+00:00  00:10
3  2012-10-01        15     0    15  2012-10-01 00:15:00+00:00  00:15
4  2012-10-01        20     0    20  2012-10-01 00:20:00+00:00  00:20
5  2012-10-01        25     0    25  2012-10-01 00:25:00+00:00  00:25
6  2012-10-01        30     0    30  2012-10-01 00:30:00+00:00  00:30
7  2012-10-01        35     0    35  2012-10-01 00:35:00+00:00  00:35
8  2012-10-01        40     0    40  2012-10-01 00:40:00+00:00  00:40
```

Comment: Alexander, and everyone else: In the end this answer worked best with my data and was useful in providing additional time metrics.

Answer (score 2):

```
from datetime import time
import pandas as pd
def to_time(x):
    hours, mn = divmod(x,60)
    return  time(hours,mn)

df["interval"] = df["interval"].apply(to_time)
```

Output:

```
         date  interval
0  2012-10-01  00:00:00
1  2012-10-01  00:05:00
2  2012-10-01  00:10:00
3  2012-10-01  00:15:00
4  2012-10-01  00:20:00
5  2012-10-01  00:25:00
6  2012-10-01  00:30:00
7  2012-10-01  00:35:00
8  2012-10-01  00:40:00
```

Or with read_csv and just incrementing the hours:

```
from datetime import time
import pandas as pd
def to_time(x):
    hours, mn = divmod(int(x), 60)
    return "{:02}:{:02}".format(hours, mn)
df = pd.read_csv("test.csv", date_parser=to_time, parse_dates=["interval"])
print(df)
```

Which if we change the last "interval" to `2355` outputs:

```
         date interval
0  2012-10-01    00:00
1  2012-10-01    00:05
2  2012-10-01    00:10
3  2012-10-01    00:15
4  2012-10-01    00:20
5  2012-10-01    00:25
6  2012-10-01    00:30
7  2012-10-01    00:35
8  2012-10-01    39:15
```

Comment: @padraig These are great but didn't work with my actual data, which is my fault. I've updated the question to elucidate the problem.

Comment: @Jonathan, ah ok so you just want to increase the hour and minutes or will we be taking days etc,, into account? Try the edit and see if we are on the same page, if not we will need to use datetime

Answer (score 2):

Just format it as a string.

Method 1 (using the old style):

```
"%02d:%02d" % (int(interval / 60), interval % 60)
```

Method 2 (using the newer style):

```
"{:02d}:{:02d}".format(int(interval / 60), interval % 60)
```